# Why can I not push_back a unique_ptr into a vector?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

What is wrong with this program?

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;

    int x(1);
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr2x(&x);
    vec.push_back(ptr2x); //This tiny command has a vicious error.

    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/memory:64,
                 from main.cpp:6:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>, _Tp* = std::unique_ptr<int>*]':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:745:6:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >, value_type = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
main.cpp:16:21:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:207:7: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = int, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<int>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:105:9: error: used here
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/vector:69:0,
                 from main.cpp:7:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h: In member function 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<int>&}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<int>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> > >, typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Base::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = std::unique_ptr<int>*]':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:749:4:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int> >, value_type = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
main.cpp:16:21:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:207:7: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = int, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<int>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> = std::unique_ptr<int>]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:314:4: error: used here
```

Answer (score 426, accepted):

You need to move the [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
vec.push_back(std::move(ptr2x));
```

`unique_ptr` guarantees that a single `unique_ptr` container has ownership of the held pointer.  This means that you can't make copies of a `unique_ptr` (because then two `unique_ptr`s would have ownership), so you can only move it.

Note, however, that your current use of `unique_ptr` is incorrect.  You cannot use it to manage a pointer to a local variable.  The lifetime of a local variable is managed automatically:  local variables are destroyed when the block ends (e.g., when the function returns, in this case).  You need to dynamically allocate the object:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(1));
```

In C++14 we have an even better way to do so:

```
make_unique<int>(5);
```

Comment: Since there can be only one, one should also be able to pass a temporary directly to the vector: `vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1)));`. `unique_ptr` can also use a custom deleter (which does nothing), but then one must take into account that the address of the local variable becomes invalid at the end of the scope.

Comment: Another option is to use `emplace_back`. e.g. `vec.emplace_back(new int(1));`

Comment: @deft_code:  No, that is not safe.  The `emplace_back` operation can throw, and if it does, the dynamically allocated `int` will be leaked.  The rule of thumb is that all dynamic allocations should be owned by a named smart pointer to avoid leakiness.

Comment: Or returned from a function: see `make_shared`.

Comment: make_shared() returns a shared_ptr, not a unique_ptr. Unfortunately, there is no make_unique() in C++11; an unfortunate omission that hopefully will be fixed in C++14

Comment: @cdmh Why would you need a `make_unique()` ? I can see that `make_shared()` allocates one bigger block of memory at the time instead of two blocks as when you use `new`, so is faster. but I don´t see the advantadge od having it for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @FKaria make_unique() would mean that `new` never needs to be invoked directly, which changes the programmer's mindset and avoids (significantly reduces) memory leaks. Advice like "Avoid new and delete" can then appear in the next edition of Meyers/Alexandrescu/Sutter's book :)

Comment: [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) made it to C++14. Please mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: @cdmh On the other hand, `make_unique()` can be used with an Initializer List while `new` can.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis but ```std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v {
    std::move(std::make_unique<int>(1)),
  };``` does not work

Comment: Pushing instances of things into a collection should look clean and be easy to get right (talking about more interesting things than int pointers). It is unfortunate that C++ requires such unwieldy syntax for something that other languages make look easy.

Answer (score 34):

[std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has no copy constructor.  You create an instance and then ask the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to copy that instance during initialisation.

```
error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::uniqu
e_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = int, _Tp_D
eleter = std::default_delete<int>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter> =
 std::unique_ptr<int>]'
```

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and
>   MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible
>   or CopyAssignable.

The following works with the new [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) calls.

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< int > > vec;
vec.emplace_back( new int( 1984 ) );
```

See [using unique_ptr with standard library containers](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/20/c11-using-unique_ptr-with-standard-library-containers) for further reading.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector#comment11813799_3283795) - using `emplace_x()` functions are unsafe when using smart pointers.

Comment: So what's the best way to store an unique_ptr into vector? It's extremely slow compared with raw pointer as I tested.

Comment: @user2189731: that's pretty strange, both `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` are templated classes which should allow heavy compiler optimization. The only thing `std::unique_ptr` does is prevent copy assignment, everything else should be just optimized away to raw pointer access.