# Calling push_back on a std::vector of objects (not pointers) has serious side effects. So would pointers be better?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

This follows on from my previous question, where I was slow to supply all the information so I am creating a new question in the hope of more input. Given:

```
    struct otherClass {
        ImportantObj    *ptrToImpObj;
        otherClass() {ptrToImpObj = NULL;}
    };
    struct anEntry {
        Thing *thing;
        std::vector<otherClass> *iDM2P2H;
        anEntry(Thing *tg, std::vector<sqdDMPair> *dM2Pair = NULL)
            : thing(tg), iDM2P2H(dM2Pair) {}
        ~anEntry() {delete iDM2P2H;}
    };
    std::vector<anEntry *> aQueue;
    std::vector<anEntry> bQueue;
    void aMethod () {
        Thing thingy = &(masterArrayOfThings[42]);
        aQueue.push_back(new anEntry(thingy, iDM2P2H));
    }
    void bMethod () {
        Thing thingy = &(masterArrayOfThings[42]);
        bQueue.push_back(anEntry(thingy, iDM2P2H));
    }
```

The second method will invoke the dtor on the memory shared between the two objects involved with the copy constructor.

In this case I feel I should be using pointers inside my vector and aQueue is preferable to bQueue.

Thanks.

_***EDIT*_**

Let's say I'll have 20 `aQueue`'s and they will be cleared and `iDM2P2H` replaced **hundreds** (thousands?) of times a second as the AI route evaluation sees fit.

Comment: 1 thing at a time.  Your anEntry class is horrible.  Fix that first.

Comment: I mean make it handle it's resources properly. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for starters.

Comment: Rather than following the "rule of 3" and deep copying to satisfy my dtor, it would be more maintainable to use pointers in the stead of objects.

Comment: You need reference-counting then.

Comment: @John, you should follow the "rule of 3" OR forbid access to the copy constructor/operator=. Failing to implement all three but still leaving the default implementations in place is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: I don't think you understand how simple this would be with pointers, the 'classes' or 'structs' are merely groupings of primitives and pointers to save having parallel arrays.

Comment: @John: That's the most absolutely ridiculous thing I've heard.  But I won't argue with you about it.

Comment: @bdonlan, ok, good call, I'll ditch the copy ctor/op=

Comment: @John - you need to follow the "rule of 3" or your class will be far too fragile.  One way to deal with the "rule of 3" without having to perform deep copying is to make the class non-copyable: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-copyable_Mixin

Comment: If your class is meant to share the vectors, then use shared_ptr.  Then you don't have to worry about copy constructors *or* destructors.

Comment: It's not meant to share, but as you see by using objects in vectors I need to assign. You are all being very pro-structured object orientation. I must get back to some lead fumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how expensive and big your objects are. Having a vector of objects is ok if they're small, but if they're big or expensive<sup>1</sup>, all the copying/constructing/destructing can add up to a large performance hit, in which case you should use pointers (and then you have to manage the memory for all the objects, etc).

<sup>1</sup> A class can be small and expensive if it doesn't have many data members (so it's not big in size) but manages expensive resources that are changed when it is copied, destroyed, or created.

Answer (score 2):

About deletion of `iDM2P2H`, either now or ever in the future, your program is going to cause that error. If you set the same pointer in two objects, sooner or later they will both die and their destructors will try to `delete` the same memory. If you use pointers and `new` the objects, the problem persists when you delete the `anEntry` objects.

The solution is simply to avoid deleting `iDM2P2H` in the `anEntry` destructor, and delete it in the same context of whoever created it. That is for example if it was created at program startup, you could delete it when you have finished your need for it, in the main execution path of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is your `anEntry` copy constructor is broken. The default copy constructor (`anEntry (const anEntry &)`) simply copies all members; with your class's explicit destructor, this results in double freeing. The same applies for the default `operator=`. Per the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), if you define any one of a destructor, copy constructor, and `operator=`, you should generally implement the other two (or forbid them by making them private and unimplemented); otherwise there's a good chance the default implementation of one of them will cause problems like this.

Now, the `vector` class requires a working copy constructor. This is part of the `vector` contract. If your class has a missing (ie, forbidden by making it private) copy constructor, the compiler will error out, preventing these "serious side effects". If the class has a *broken* copy constructor, well, that's not `vector`'s fault.

Note that you may want to consider using RAII-style allocation in your `anEntry` class. For example, make `iDM2P2H` a `std::vector<otherClass>` instead of `std::vector<otherClass> *`. By doing so, you won't need a destructor *at all*, and if the default copy semantics are acceptable to you, you might be able to do with the default copy constructor in this case.

That said, `vector`'s copying may indeed entail significant overhead at times. There are a number of things you can do to work around this; however I would recommend *against* a raw `std::vector<anEntry *>` - the reason being that this won't clean up the pointed-to elements automatically.

Instead, use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<anEntry>>` (if you have a C++0x compiler) or [`boost::ptr_vector<anEntry>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). This will give you the automatic destruction benefits of `vector` but will not copy any elements (as the vector is a vector of pointers to objects). Note that in the `unique_ptr` case you will need to [use `std::move`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/push-back-of-unique-ptr/3283795#3283795) to add elements to the vector.

Alternately, if your compiler supports C++0x move-aware containers, you could write a move constructor:

```
struct anEntry {
    Thing *thing;
    std::vector<sqdDMPair> iDM2P2H;

    anEntry(Thing *thing_, std::vector<sqdDMPair> *vec = NULL)
      : thing(thing_), iDM2P2H(vec ? *vec : std::vector<sqdDMPair>())
    { }

    // Default copy constructor and destructor OK

    // Move constructor
    anEntry(anEntry &&src)
      : thing(src.thing), iDM2P2H(std::move(src.iDM2P2H)) { }

    anEntry &operator=(anEntry &&other) {
      if (this != &other) {
        thing = other.thing;
        iDM2P2H = std::move(other.iDM2P2H);
      }
    }
};
```

Using `std::move` allows the contents of `iDM2P2H` to be moved to the new position in the outer vector *without copying recursively*. However, C++0x support is still in its infancy, and your compiler and STL may or may not support it yet (if `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` compiles, you're probably ok).

Comment: Or `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.  Less good than C++0x, but better than Boost.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't written the copy ctor as it would be easier not to have use of it.

Comment: @John, if you don't want the copy ctor, fine, _delete it_. Boost has a nice `boost::noncopyable` class for this. But don't leave a copy constructor around that will silently cause heap corruption if you accidentally use it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really have objects that contain pointers to shared data/resources, maybe you could consider using `std::shared_ptr<my_shared_type>` rather than just having `delete` called in the `dtor`.

Using `std::vector<>` of pointers might make the issues go away for awhile, but it's potentially just masking a more fundamental issue of shared resource management.

Hope this helps.