# When to delete elements added to std::vector?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and have a question regarding memory management.

In the header, I have this:

```
std::vector<Obstacle::Obstacle*> obstacles;
```

and in the .cpp I do this:

```
Circle *circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);
obstacles.push_back(circle);
```

where `Circle` is a subclass of `Obstacle`.

My question is when should I call `delete` on the elements which are in the vector? I have heard each `new` should be balanced by a `delete`. Do I need to in the destructor loop through the vector and call `delete` on each element? Isn't there a more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call `delete` on the elements before you clear the vector, or before the vector goes out of scope **iff the vector owns the objects pointed at**. A more elegant solution is to have the vector hold [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). The particular type of smart pointer should depend on the ownership policy.
For example, a vector owning the pointed-at objects should use C++11 `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obstacle>> obstacles;
```

Of course, all of the above is under the assumption that you actually have strong reasons to use pointers. Often the best solution is the simplest ones: hold items by value:

```
std::vector<SomeType> things;
```

Note that this doesn't apply in your case, where you are storing pointers to objects derived from a base class, since storing values of base type would result in [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

**Edit**: One simple way to ensure the elements are deleted when the vector goes out of scope is to write a scope guard class:

```
template <typename CONTAINER>
struct PtrContainerGuard
{
  PtrContainerGuard(CONTAINER& container) : c_(container) {}
  ~PtrContainerGuard()
  {
    for (typename CONTAINER::iterator it = c_.begin(); it != c_.end(); ++it)
      delete (*it);
  }
private:
  CONTAINER& c_;

}
```

then

```
std::vector<Obstacle*> obstacles;
PtrContainerGuard<std::vector::Obstacle*> p(obstacles);
```

Comment: +1: This answer is a true question: who owns what, and when? Only the domain knowledge can give you a way to decide. It's the main motivation of Garbage Collectors. Add to this problem a little bit of concurrency and headache is for you! ;-)

Comment: Not the down voter, but it should be made clear that the last suggestion (holding items by value) won't work for polymorphic data.  The `std::vector<Obstacle::Obstacle>` cannot hold `Circle` objects.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I edited that a few minutes ago. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: So if I don't want to use smart pointers, I should loop through the elements and delete them in the destructor?
I don't think I can do without pointers as Obstacle is an abstract class (?).

Comment: @MichaelFrost assuming the vector owns the objects pointed at, then yes, you will have to iterate and delete.

Comment: For example Obstacles are owned by Scene and shared by Renderer. You can decide only by drawing all your software architecture with UML. And using dynamic diagrams, not only statics ones.

Comment: an [addition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3283795/847349) to the solution with std::unique_ptr

Comment: @MichaelFrost another option is to write a small wrapper scope guard class that makes sure to delete the elements. I added an example.

Comment: The usage of the PtrContainerGuard is the same as composition, it's very dangerous because pointers may be shared and used after delete. It's not a syntax problem but a semantic one. The live cycle of an application object should be analyzed as a high level, not at low level

Comment: @Aubin here, the guard is only a safe replacement for iterating and deleting before leaving scope. Of course, the same ownership issues apply.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, you're right but be careful when you give a shotgun to a guy. Once a day he will use it... ;-) Analysis should be done before programming with the Occam's razor in mind. Be simple, be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use shared_ptr? You don't have to create new objects and worry about deleting them if you use them.

```
typedef shared_ptr<Obstacle> ObstaclePtr;
int main()
{
std::vector<ObstaclePtr> obstacles;
//Create objets using shared_ptr and push them in vector
ObstaclePtr obstacle1(new Circle());
obstacles.push_back(obstacle1);

ObstaclePtr obstacle2(new Circle());
obstacles.push_back(obstacle2);
//When vector obstacles goes out of scope here, all circles inside are destructed!
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a more elegant way. Throw away all your pointers.

```
std::vector<Obstacle::Obstacle> obstacles;

Circle circle(x, y, radius);
obstacls.push_back(circle);
```

Nothing was `new`'ed, nothing needs to be `delete`d, you save a memory allocation, and access to the objects stored in the vector becomes more efficient.

Also, your code will no longer make the eyes bleed of more experienced C++ developers.

All in all, I call that a win. :)

Comment: Isn't this suggestion vulnerable to slicing?

Comment: And you've pushed only the Obstacle part into the vector. All the circle-specific information is lost...

Comment: This answer not the question. Composition (in opposition to aggregation) don't solve all problems. Once two or more objects share the same instance of another object, pointers go back (even 'smart')

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: yes, it is. I could say I'd just woken up when I wrote it, but ultimately, yes, you're right, it's a brainfart and it causes slicing and undefined behavior. In this case, smart pointers would be a better solution. The point I intended to get across, however, stands: don't use (raw) pointers (well, don't use them like *this*, at any rate). Don't put yourself in a situation where you have to explicitly call `delete` *ever*. Only call `new` if you then *immediately* store the resulting pointer into a smart pointer of some sort. I will fix up my answer when I have a moment. :)