# std::vector<T> compile error "T cannot appear in a constant-expression"

Tags: c++, g++, llvm

First off, my code compiles and runs fine on Mac OS X with compiler

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
```

but on Ubuntu with compiler

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

it won't compile.

In my header I have

```
std::vector<Obstacle::Obstacle*> obstacles;
```

which gives the following compilation error in Ubuntu:

```
error: ‘Obstacle::Obstacle’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Any ideas of what I need to change to make it work?
Is there some magical compile flag I should use on Ubuntu to make it work just as on OS X?

Thank you

EDIT: `Obstacle` is a class.

Comment: What is this `Obstacles::Obstacles` thing? Please show the definition. Your question as is requires us to read your invisible code / read your mind.

Comment: If you're new to C++ and using an `std::vector` of pointers, there's a good chance you'll end up with a memory leak (assuming you `new` the objects being pushed into the vector). You need to make sure you `delete` every vector element before it goes out of scope. But, instead of going through all this trouble, it is better to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obstacle>>` instead.

Comment: @Prætorian thanks for the comment, it was discussed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12880803/251666) question from earlier today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass constructor pointer as stored type.

Instead of

```
std::vector<Obstacle::Obstacle*> obstacles;
```

try

```
std::vector<Obstacle*> obstacles;
```

Comment: Works! Will accept when it lets me in 8 minutes. I'm new to C++. I thought "Obstacle::" just set the namespace? Or is that just for functions...?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: the redundancy might well be the heart of the issue though.

Comment: @PiotrNycz I know there is no such thing, if you have better name for this I'll be happy to update it.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423380/why-are-redundant-class-name-qualifiers-allowed) a question on some the oddities of using this `Foo::Foo` syntax to refer to a class. Different compilers handle it differently.

Comment: @Bartek - see other answer. In C++ constructors are not ordinary functions/methods. You cannot take address of it. You cannot define type like address to constructor. Your advice is correct, but your explanation is wrong. This is just compiler inconsistency - `Obstacle` should be the same as `Obstacle::Obstacle` but this compiler does not want to treat this in this manner. That's all.

Comment: @PiotrNycz that's incorrect. `Obstacle` is not the same as `Obstacle::Obstacle`. The latter names the constructor (and is ill-formed in that context), and the former names the class. If you want to name the class with the latter kind-of-syntax, you can say `class Obstacle::Obstacle`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - Just used incorrect "mental shortcut". I mean t this very context `vector<Obstacle::Obstacle>` - vector definition `vector<class T>` - so `Obstacle::Obstacle` is used with `class`/`typename` in vector defined like in the question. Am I right or still wrong?

Comment: Huh? that's still just as incorrect as if you passed `int()` to a template non-type parameter of type `int`, because `int()` is a type. Whatever parameter you are passing to does not change the argument's interpretation here.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently `Obstacle` is just a class.

Amazingly, the following also works, tested in g++ 4.2, g++ 4.3, g++ 4.4, clang++ 2.9, and clang++ 3.1:

```
std::vector<Obstacle::Obstacle::Obstacle::Obstacle::Obstacle*> obstacles;
```

Multiple versions of g++ and multiple versions of clang compiled the above.

<strike>g++ 4.5 and 4.6 have problems with this construct. This looks like a g++ bug, versions 4.5 and higher. So why should this be legal?</strike>

This is a bug in pre 4.5 g++, clang, and apparently other compilers. The relevant portion of the standard is 3.4.3.1, para 1a:

> If the nested-name-specifier nominates a class C, and the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C (clause 9), the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C. Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a constructor definition that appears outside of the class definition.

In other words, `Obstacle::Obstacle` is illegal except when used in an out of line definition of a constructor for class `Obstacle`.

So how are these compilers parsing this? Those compilers are treating `Obstacle::Obstacle` as having special meaning only in the case of an out of line definition of a constructor. Otherwise, `Obstacle::Obstacle` follows the injected name rules, but ignore the fact that that rule does not apply here. `Obstacle::Obstacle*` isn't a pointer to the constructor because constructors don't have names. `Obstacle::Obstacle*` instead means whatever `Obstacle*` means when evaluated from within the context of the class `Obstacle`. But inside the class, `Obstacle*` is still a pointer to an instance of class `Obstacle`. `Obstacle::Obstacle*` is just an `Obstacle*`, as is `Obstacle::Obstacle::Obstacle*`, and so on. Pile on as many `Obstacle`s you want and it's still just an `Obstacle*`.

Comment: No, this is a bug in gcc<4.5 and Clang. Refer to http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8263

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - Answer fixed. That bug report can be simplified greatly. clang accepts `A::A a;` The standard says this is an error, not UB. Diagnosis is required.

Comment: but i reporred the bug for the lulz and for having a rejects-valid bug which is much worse than an accepts-invalid bug :-)