# what to use in place of std::map::emplace?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

For containers such as `std::map< std::string, std::unique_ptr< Foo >>`, it looks like `emplace()` has yet to be implemented in stdc++ as of gcc 4.7.2.

Unfortunately, I can't store Foo directly by value as it is an abstract super-class.

As a simple, but inefficient, place-holder, I've just been using `std::map< std::string, Foo* >` in conjunction with a `std::vector< std::unique_ptr< Foo >>` for garbage collection.

*Do you have a interim solution that is more efficient and more easily replaced once emplace() is available?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you need `emplace()` for? Just move it in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = default;

    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    std::string name() const { return "Bar"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> m;

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Bar());
    m.insert(std::make_pair("a", std::move(p)));

    std::cout << m["a"]->name() << std::endl;
}
```

In fact, **[you should not use `emplace` with `unique_ptr`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13172888/87234)**.

As noted in my comment there, I now consider the use of `new` in user code an error. It should be replaced with `make_unique`, so you know your resource cannot possibly leak:

```
// will be in std:: someday
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair("a", make_unique<Bar>()));

    std::cout << m["a"]->name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer with useable code.  Avoiding the use of `new` in user code is a valiant cause.  However, suppose instead of constructing a new instance of Bar, I need to insert into the map a `foo->clone()` because I don't know what kind of `Foo` I have?  How would you make `Foo* Bar::clone()` avoid calling `new`?  Or is this ok, because it wouldn't be considered client code?

Comment: Coincidentally I just dealt with that today. Make your clone function return `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` instead.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but what if the user of the foo->clone() wants a shared_ptr?

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky: You can construct a shared_ptr from a unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you may use, `boost` containers which support most C++ 11 features even under a C++ 03 compiler and have same layout as `std` containers and then when you have then feature in you `std` you can just switch a name space!