# How to uniform initialize map of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, smart-pointers, uniform-initialization

I have this code to initialize map from into to unique_ptr.

```
auto a = unique_ptr<A>(new A());
map<int, unique_ptr<A>> m;
m[1] = move(a);
```

Can I use uniform initialize this? I tried

```
map<int, unique_ptr<A>> m {{1, unique_ptr<A>(new A())}};
```

But I got an error.

Some part of error message is

```
In instantiation of 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<A, std::default_delete<A> > >&}; _Val = std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<A> >]': ... In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/memory:81:0,
                 from smart_pointer_map.cpp:3: /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

   ^
```

Comment: What was the error?  Did the program crash when you ran it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I not push\_back a unique\_ptr into a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`unique_ptr` is movable, but not copyable.  `initializer_list` requires copyable types; you can't move something out of an `initializer_list`.  Unfortunately, I believe what you want to do isn't possible.

Incidentally, it would be more helpful to know which specific error you got.  Otherwise, we have to guess whether you did something wrong and what, or whether what you want to do isn't implemented in your compiler, or is simply not supported in the language.  (This is most helpful along with minimal reproduction code.)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround and especially when you want to have a `const map` containing `unique_ptr`, you can use a `lambda` executed in place. It is not an **initializer list**, but the result is similar:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<int>> MapType;
auto const mapInstance([]()
{
   MapType m;
   m.insert(MapType::value_type(0x0023, std::make_unique<int>(23)));
   return m;
}());
```

or even simpler without typedef using make_pair:

```
auto const mapInstance([]()
{
   std::map<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<int>> m;
   m.insert(std::make_pair(0x0023, std::make_unique<int>(23)));
   return m;
}());
```