# Initialize const static std::map with unique_ptr as value

Tags: c++

The question is similar with [Initialize static std::map with unique_ptr as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213088/initialize-static-stdmap-with-unique-ptr-as-value) . 
But in my question map should be readonly. 
so, how can i initilize static const map, where value is std::unique_ptr:

```cpp
static const std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>
```

In this case initialization inside static function doesn't work,

```cpp
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> init()
{
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> mp;
    mp[0] = std::make_unique<MyClass>();
    mp[1] = std::make_unique<MyClass>();
    //...etc
    return mp;
}
```

Initilization via initilization list doesn't work as well

```cpp
    const std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> = {
        { 0, std::make_unique<MyClass>() }
```

Comment: Did you try `const std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> mp = {...}`?

Comment: First, what is the specific compilation error you are getting? Second, please provide motivation for your static const map. It seems like there would be a much easier way to accomplish your requirements this using other design patterns. Also, given @felix 's comment, I think you have a typo with your description of "Initialization via initialization list...".

Comment: The initialization list requires copy construction, so doesn't work with unique pointers. Known issue on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uniform initialize map of unique\_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180673/how-to-uniform-initialize-map-of-unique-ptr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly instantiate a `const map` with `initializer list` of `std::unique_ptr` because:

> constructing from std::initializer-list copies its contents.

and you cannot copy `std::unique_ptr`.

---

Therefore, you can "dynamically" create the map (inside a function) and move the content into a `const map`.

That is:

```
using Map = std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>;

static Map GenMap() {
  Map m;
  m[0] = std::make_unique<int>(0);
  // ...
  return m;
}

static const Map globalStaticMap = GenMap();
```

---

*Lambda* can avoid defining the static function making your code more compact.

```
static const Map globalStaticMap = []() {
  Map m;
  m[0] = std::make_unique<int>(0);
  // ...
  return m;
}();
```

Comment: An immediately-invoked lambda can be great here too.