# Using a vector of unique pointers to an <Employee> vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, ostream

For a school assignment, I am trying to use a vector of unique pointer's to Employee objects to access the Employee data, but can't figure out the syntax/compiler errors. Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Have to use a vector of smart pointers in this fashion.

Here is the applicable code:

```
// Create an Employee
Employee EmpRec;

// Assign value to a uniqueptr
unique_ptr<Employee> TempEmp;
*TempEmp = EmpRec;

// Create a vector of unique_ptr<Employee>
vector<unique_ptr<Employee>> EmpVect;

// Push the TempEmp pointer onto the vector
EmpVect.push_back(TempEmp);

// Iterate through vector, calling display function 
//that prints the values of various data inside the Employee object
for (size_t i = 0; i < EmpVect.size(); ++i){
    (EmpVect[i])->display(cout);
}
```

This is how my Display function is defined:

```
void display(std::ostream& cout) const{
    // print data members using cout <<
}
```

When trying to compile this, I get the following error:

d:\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not push\_back a unique\_ptr into a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Calling `push_back` like that will attempt to copy the `unique_ptr` into the vector. You can't copy `unique_ptr`s! Instead, you need to move it into the vector:

```
EmpVect.push_back(std::move(TempEmp));
```

You do, however, have another problem. Your `unique_ptr` is not initialised to point at any particular allocated `Employee`, yet you then try to assign to that object. That's not good. Instead, you should dynamically allocate the `Employee` and pass it to the `unique_ptr` constructor:

```
unique_ptr<Employee> TempEmp(new Employee());
```

Or preferably, use [an implementation](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt) of [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (which will be available in C++14).

Comment: you can also use EmpVect.emplace_back( TempEmp )

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky You can? Pretty sure you'd still need to `std::move` it.

Comment: yes, you are right, it needs to be EmpVect.emplace_back( std::move(TempEmp) )