# Error while declaring a class with std::vector of structs containing std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

Although having worked several years with C#, getting things done in C++ is sometime still difficult for me. I fully embrace the usage of smart pointers, but now I'm facing the following puzzle

I have a struct `Foo`, e.g.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar) : m_myBar(std::move(bar)) {}

 private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_myBar;           
};
```

In a different class, I want to have a vector containing instances of Foo, but the following line

```
 std::vector<Foo> m_Foos;
```

yields compile errors saying that the copy constructor is deleted. In the SO thread "[Why can I not push_back a unique_ptr into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)" an explanation as well as a remedy is given. However, there the question concerns a vector of unique pointers whereas I have a vector of structs containing a unique pointer. The suggested solution is to use move semantics, but how does that apply in my situation? Or should I be doing something else?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I'm using Qt Creator 3.1.2 based on Qt 5.3.1 with mingw32-make.exe. Does that matter?

Comment: Which compiler? I assume mingw gcc, which should be OK. Visual Studio's compiler cannot generate move ctors automatically. But the vector line itself is not causing the error, see link in my answer. Is it perhaps enclosed in a class, which would affect that class's copy ctor? IOW, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, `m_Foos` is actually a data member of another class (I'll call it `FooHolder`). If you didn't provide a copy constructor for `FooHolder`, the compiler will generate one automatically. That copy constructor will call the copy constructors of all data members of `FooHolder`, including `m_Foos`. Of course, the copy constructor of `std::vector<Foo>` contains a compilation error, since `Foo` is not copyable. This is probably why you're getting the error.

You'll have to provide an appropriate copy constructor for `FooHolder`, if you are able to and want that class to be copyable. Otherwise, you can just declare a move constructor (possibly defaulted), which will make the copy constructor deleted:

```
struct FooHolder
{
  FooHolder(FooHolder&&) = default;

private:
  std::vector<Foo> m_Foos;
};
```

Comment: OP may still have the error while trying to `push_back` lvalue of `Foo` as `Foo` is not copy-constructible, this is worth to mention

Comment: @PiotrS. The OP claims the error came from the definition of the vector - it did not. And the answer addressed moving the struct itself as well.

Comment: In VS2013 move constructors can't be defaulted for whatever reason, so you need to define it explicitly (i.e. `: m_Foos(std::move(rhs.m_Foos))`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy unique pointers. You can only *move* them:

```
Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar) : m_myBar(std::move(bar)) {}
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @angew and Kerrek. Thanks for pointing out that I cannot type :-s In my original question I forgot to include that I use std::move, which you both mentioned. I've updated my original question to reflect this. When deleting the line std::vector<Foo> m_Foos, the program compiles and I can even construct Foo objects, so I'm pretty sure that the vector is causing the problem.

Comment: @SimonAx: what operations do you perform over the vector? and do you try to copy that Other class with `std::vector` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. I did not perform any operation over the vector yet. Before going further with pushing back elements I wanted to verify that the program compiled and it didn't.