# Replacing unique_ptr object in a vector with Another unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I want to replace the unique_ptr object at that index with another one, which is essentially "deleting" the pointer currently in the vector, and moving classObj into that spot.

```
std::unique_ptr<ClassName> classObj(new className());
classNameStorage[5] = classObj; // classNameStorage.size() > 5
```

The code above, using the assignment operator is invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not push\_back a unique\_ptr into a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)

Comment: On an aside note, the first line can be expressed as `auto classObj = std::make_unique<ClassName>()`. According to Scott Meyers, the advantage of `std::make_unique` (other than having less to type) is that it ensures that the `unique_ptr` takes ownership immediately upon instantiation of `T`. This makes a difference in more complex expressions and in the presence of exceptions. A compiler is allowed to evaluate `x(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T), y())` by first evaluating `new T`, then `y()`, and then the `unique_ptr` constructor on the former. In such case, a throw from `y()` will leak a `T`.

Comment: What is the type of classNameStorage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classNameStorage[5] = std::move(classObj);`

`std::unique_ptr` is a move-only class.  Thus, in situations where an instance has a name (i.e. is an *lvalue*), you must wrap it in `std::move` ("convert" into an *rvalue*) to have the data moved out.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector?rq=1) for more details.