# Smart pointer for holding forward references to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, forward-declaration

Assume I have this header:

```
#include <vector>

class B;

class A
{
...
private:
    std::vector<what_pointer B> holder;
};
```

I don't want to include B in the header so I made the "class B" forward reference to it. However the header has that container for B's, and since B's true header is only included in the Cpp, I must use pointers to B inside the container.

Obviously I could create a destructor for A which goes through the "holder" and de allocates all the memory areas the pointers are pointing to. But I'm wondering if there is a smart pointer that "should" be used in this situation instead of a raw pointers.

Comment: Yes, you should use smart pointers. What are you worrying about?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` seems even better, or just use *pimpl* idiom completely.

Comment: `unique_ptr` if you want to mirror value semantics in the closest way. Just remember [that it has no copy-ctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector).

Comment: Note that in C++17, it would be allowed to use incomplete type in `std::vector` (and currently most compiler already support it even if it is pedantically UB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In c++17, you may simply do

  ```
  class B;

  class A
  {
  public:
  ...
      ~A(); // define in cpp, as B definition should be known for destruction
  private:
      std::vector<B> holder;
  };
  ```

  as incomplete types would be allowed for `vector`.
- Currently, you may do

  ```
  class A
  {
  public:
      //...
      A(const A&); // should be reimplemented to copy holder
      A& operator =(const A&); // should be reimplemented to copy pimpl
      A(A&&) = default;
      A& operator =(A&&) = default;

      ~A();
  private:
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> holder;
  };
  ```

  And then

  ```
  #include "B.h"

  // define in cpp, as B definition should be known
  ~A::A() = default;

  A::A(const A& rhs) {
      for (const auto& b : rhs.holder) {
           holder.push_back(std::make_unique<B>(*b));
      }
  }

  // ...
  ```
- Or use pimpl idiom completely

  ```
  class A
  {
  public:
      //...
      A(const A&); // should be reimplemented to copy pimpl
      A& operator =(const A&); // should be reimplemented to copy pimpl
      A(A&&) = default;
      A& operator =(A&&) = default;

      ~A();
  private:
      struct Pimpl;
      std::unique_ptr<Pimpl> pimpl;
  };
  ```

  And then

  ```
  #include "B.h"

  struct A::Pimpl {
      // ...
      std::vector<B> holder;
  };

  // define in cpp, as B definition should be known
  ~A::A() = default;

  A::A(const A& rhs) : pimpl(std::make_unique<Pimpl>(rhs.pimpl)) {}

  // ...
  ```

Comment: Could you explain why exactly I need to redefine the copy&move constructors ? Isn't the implementation you "redefined" exactly the default implementation anyway ?

Comment: @GeorgeH: `std::unique_ptr` is not copy-able, so you have to implement the copy-constructor to be equivalent to the `vector<B>` version. And if you use `std::shared_ptr` instead, the default copy is not what you want (you want new object, not shared references).

Comment: I tried implementing this method, doesn't seem to work, maybe because I'm using a map instead of a vector and moving the pointer into a std::pair. It does seem to work using shared_ptr though ... is there any problem using that instead ?

Comment: @GeorgeH: How is your `map` ? I suggest to use pimpl idiom BTW.

Comment: std::map< std::string, std::shared_ptr<B> > m_mymap; pimpl idiom seems to convoluted tbh, e.g. would not make for readable code.