# How add/remove to/from vector<unique_ptr>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers

I use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` because it's not count reference and is faster. You can change it to `shared_ptr`. My question is how to add/remove properly to/from vector of smart pointers?
Key lines are here:

```
CEO->add(std::move(headSales));
CEO->remove(headSales);
```

Code:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class Employee
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string department;
    std::uint32_t salary;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> subordinates;

public:
    Employee(std::string n, std::string d, std::uint32_t s) : name(n), department(d), salary(s)
    {}
    bool operator==(const Employee &e)
    {
        return name == e.name && department == e.department && salary == e.salary;
    }
    void add(std::unique_ptr<Employee> e)
    {
        subordinates.push_back(e);
    }
    void remove(const std::unique_ptr<Employee> e)
    {
        subordinates.erase(std::remove(subordinates.begin(), subordinates.end(), e), subordinates.end());
    }
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> getSubordinates() const
    {
        return subordinates;
    }
};
#endif  //EMPLOYEE_H


#include "Employee.h"


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Employee> CEO = std::make_shared<Employee>("John", "CEO", 30000);
    std::unique_ptr<Employee> headSales = std::make_shared<Employee>("Robert", "Head Sales", 20000);
    CEO->add(std::move(headSales));
    CEO->remove(headSales);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question... Do you have a problem, what have you tried?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T> var = std::make_shared<T>(/*blah*/);` ... why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not push\_back a unique\_ptr into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)

Comment: missing some `std::move`.

Comment: Your data model is wrong it is saying: An Employee OWNS their subordinates.  Think about this for a minute, if your boss leaves you get deleted.

Comment: push_back is a copy operation. unique_ptr forbids copy, as then it would not be unique. You need move.

Comment: This code doesn't compile; make shared won't convert to a unique ptr.  Why use smart pointers at all in the vector?

Comment: "I use unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr because it's not count reference and is faster." They do two rather different things; choose based on **what they do**, not on how fast one or the other may be.

Comment: Hint: `vector::emplace_back()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<Employee> CEO = std::make_shared<Employee>("John", "CEO", 30000);
>      ^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^
> ```

This is wrong because a shared pointer is not convertible to a unique pointer. It is unclear whether you intend to have shared or unique ownership.

---

> ```
>  CEO->remove(headSales);
>  subordinates.push_back(e);
> ```

These are wrong because you're trying to copy a unique pointer. Unique pointers aren't copyable however - otherwise they wouldn't remain unique. Instead, you must move from the original pointer:

```
subordinates.push_back(std::move(e));
```

Using a unique pointer as an argument by value for `Employee::remove` is not sensible in the first place. More about that below.

---

> ```
> std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> getSubordinates() const
> {
>     return subordinates;
> }
> ```

This time you're trying to copy a vector of unique pointers. The problem remains the same - the pointers are not copyable. You cannot move the vector either since the function is const. Perhaps you intend to simply give read access. That could be achieved by returning a reference:

```
 const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>>& getSubordinates() const
```

---

> ```
> CEO->add(std::move(headSales));
> CEO->remove(headSales);
> ```

You're using a pointer that you already moved from. The ownership of the unique pointer was transferred uniquely to `add`, so using it after the move is no longer meaningful.

As I mentioned, it makes little sense to use a unique pointer as the argument by value for remove. In order to have the unique pointer, you would have to own that pointer - uniquely. Therefore the vector couldn't possibly own it. You could instead refer to the pointer that is contained in the vector, and use that:

```
void remove(const std::unique_ptr<Employee>& e)

CEO->remove(CEO->getSubordinates().back());
```

---

> You can change it to `shared_ptr`.

Well, that would be much simpler. Replace all `unique` with `shared`, and remove that one `std::move` and the program will be well-formed.

---

PS. `std::remove` that you want is in the `<algorithm>` header which you forgot to include.

PPS. It is unclear to me why an employee should have any kind of ownership of other employees - unique or shared. I suggest that all employees are owned by something else - say `Company`, and employees only have non-owning association. I suggest `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has no need for unique or shared pointers.

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class Employee
{
protected:
  std::string name;
  std::string department;
  std::uint32_t salary;
  std::vector<Employee> subordinates;

public:
  Employee(std::string n, std::string d, std::uint32_t s) : name(n), department(d), salary(s)
  {}
  bool operator==(const Employee &e) const
  {
    return name == e.name && department == e.department && salary == e.salary && subordinates == e.subordinates;
  }
  void add(Employee e)
  {
    subordinates.push_back(std::move(e));
  }
  void remove(Employee const& e)
  {
    subordinates.erase(std::remove(subordinates.begin(), subordinates.end(), e), subordinates.end());
  }
  std::vector<Employee> getSubordinates() const
  {
    return subordinates;
  }
};
#endif  //EMPLOYEE_H


#include "Employee.h"


int main()
{
  Employee CEO = {"John", "CEO", 30000};
  Employee headSales = {"Robert", "Head Sales", 20000};
  CEO->add(headSales);
  CEO->remove(headSales);
}
```

Also your `==` should be `const`, and it should compare `subordinates`.  Because it is now a vector of `Employee`, this invokes `==` recursively.