# Boost (de)serialize vector of dervied objects, use of deleted finction (unique_ptr)

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, boost, unique-ptr

I am trying to implement serialization into my project. My problem is that when I'm trying to deserialize objects, I'm getting error like:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Employee; _Dp = std::default_delete<Employee>]’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

EDIT: I added `hireIntern` and `employeeMenu` functions and I reduced some unnecessary code.

```
class Employee {  
protected:    
    int employeeID;
    std::string Name;
    std::string Surname;
    int Salary;
    bool Hired;   
public:   
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {
        ar & employeeID;
        ar & Name;
        ar & Surname;
        ar & Salary;
        ar & Hired;

    }    
    virtual ~Employee();
    Employee();
    Employee(const std::string &, const std::string &);
```

.cpp

```
#include "Employee.h"   
Employee::~Employee() = default;    
Employee::Employee() = default;   
Employee::Employee(const std::string &newName, const std::string &newSurname) : Name(newName), Surname(newSurname) {}
```

Derived, "Intern.h"

```
class Intern : public Employee {
public:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Employee>(*this);
        ar & Status;
    }

    std::string Status = "Intern";

    Intern();
    ~Intern();
    Intern(const std::string &, const std::string &);

};
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Intern);
```

.cpp

```
#include "Intern.h"   
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Intern);    
Intern::Intern() = default;   
Intern::~Intern() = default;    
Intern::Intern(const std::string &newName, const std::string &newSurname) : Employee(newName, newSurname) {}
```

Commented lines at the start causing error with deserialization.
When I ignore them, serialization implemented in `case 3:` works fine.
The problem is, I also want to load objects into vector from .txt file at start.

```
void mainMenu() {

    //std::ifstream ifs("database");
    //boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

    vector<unique_ptr<Employee>> Firm;

    //ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("root", Firm);
...

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                hireIntern(Firm);
                break;
            case 2:
                employeeMenu(Firm);
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                std::ofstream ofs("database");
                boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
                oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("root", Firm);

                return;
            }
...
```

.

```
void hireIntern(vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {
    ...
        sourceEmployee.emplace_back(new Intern(fillName, fillSurname));
```

. In functions called in `employeeMenu` I'm just editting some `Firm` vector of objects fields like `sourceEmployee[index]->setSalary(sourceEmployee[index]->getSalary() + 1000);`

```
  void employeeMenu(vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {

...

        switch (option) {

            case 1:
                Promote(sourceEmployee);
                break;
            case 2:
                Demote(sourceEmployee);
                break;
            case 3:
                fireEmployee(sourceEmployee);
                break;
            case 4:
                employeeShowcase(sourceEmployee);
                break;
            case 5:
                showHiredEmployees(sourceEmployee);
                break;
            case 6:
                showFiredEmployees(sourceEmployee);
```

When I compile code with these lines I'm getting following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/cmake-build-debug --target PROJEKT -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target PROJEKT
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/mainMenu.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/fstream:38,
                 from /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/Employee.h:8,
                 from /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/manageDatabase.h:8,
                 from /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/mainMenu.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<Employee, std::default_delete<Employee> >&}; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Employee>]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:530:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<Employee, std::default_delete<Employee> >&}; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:917:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<Employee>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/vector.hpp:102:13:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load(Archive&, std::vector<U, Allocator>&, unsigned int, mpl_::false_) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; U = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; Allocator = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/vector.hpp:173:9:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load(Archive&, std::vector<U, Allocator>&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; U = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; Allocator = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:58:13:   required from ‘static void boost::serialization::free_loader<Archive, T>::invoke(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:74:18:   [ skipping 22 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:618:18:   required from ‘void boost::archive::load(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = const boost::serialization::nvp<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee> > >]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:66:22:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:71:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_text_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:92:52:   required from ‘void boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:60:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator>>(T&) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee> > >; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/home/max/c++/PROJEKT/mainMenu.cpp:16:54:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Employee; _Dp = std::default_delete<Employee>]’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_conv.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iomanip:43,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/Employee.h:9,
                 from /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/manageDatabase.h:8,
                 from /home/max/c++/PROJEKT/mainMenu.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^
CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/mainMenu.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/mainMenu.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PROJEKT.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'PROJEKT' failed
make: *** [PROJEKT] Error 2
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to copy a `unique_ptr`. The copy constructor is deleted (`= delete;`)  to keep the pointer unique.

Comment: You showed a lot of code, but most of it is trivial and unnecessary. However, you are not showing the `hireIntern` and `employeeMenu` function, which are likely the culprit (because they are the only ones that have to do with `Firm`, which is the only place you are using a `unique_ptr`). Please show those functions, and possibly also reduce your code to the necessary minimum to demonstrate the problem. In short, [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example please.

Comment: @BoPersson I've read about that in different topics but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I reduced unnecessary code, and added `hireIntern` and `employeeMenu` functions. I hope it helps with finding a solution.

Comment: Sorry for requesting the two functions (they are not needed here), I did not notice the commented code being the problem as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your case you should use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`, because you are sharing the pointers ownership between your `main` function, `std::vector` container, `hireIntern` function, `employeeMenu` function and also `boost::serialization` routines. `unique_ptr` should only be used, when at the time just one `unique_ptr` instance is pointing at the same memory - i.e. it has a unique ownership. If you insist on using `unique_ptr` with containers and you wish to pass that container to the functions, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector) to learn how to use move semantics (because copy constructor of `unique_ptr` is deleted). Otherwise, I recommend `shared_ptr`.

EDIT ==== according to your comment

In the stacktrace that you provided you can find:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:917:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr<Employee>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/vector.hpp:102:13:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load(Archive&, std::vector<U, Allocator>&, unsigned int, mpl_::false_) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; U = std::unique_ptr<Employee>; Allocator = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Employee> >; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
```

You can see that `boost::serialization` routine instantiated by you with the type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>, "standard allocator">` is trying to execute `void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&)` which is strictly forbidden for the type `std::unique_ptr`. I guess that problem appears upon `text_iarchive` instantiation - as name suggests it is an input class and it probably calls `push_back` at some point (it can easily be confirmed, just scan quickly the boost code).

So, again, if you plan to store a smart pointer in the container that usually means that you don't really want to use `std::unique_ptr` for that purpose.

Comment: I read the question you linked. I've been already using the `emplace.back()` function in `hireIntern` which was suggested by one user. It looks like that `sourceEmployee.emplace_back(new Intern(fillName, fillSurname));` and it's called in this function: `void hireIntern(vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee)`. I don't know how `shared_ptr` boost (de)serialization implementiation should looks like

Comment: It's not your code that is calling `push_back`, it's boost. Read my edits to the answer.

Comment: You're right. I tried to use `shared_ptr` once but It didn't work. Now, I replaced all pointers with `shared_ptr` again and everything works fine! Thanks for your time.