# Sysmalloc error on vector pointer<unique ptr> on second push back

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

For a school assignment I need to keep track of multiple instances of a `Product` class.

Within the main of my program I am making a vector as follows:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product>> products;
```

On a specific condition within my main, I am passing this vector as a pointer to another function called `processData`. This one is looking like this (simplified as much as possible):

```
void processData(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product>>* products)
{
while (true)
{
    //Do something with std::cin
    //Do something with that data
    products->push_back(std::unique_ptr<Product>(new Product(dataX, dataB)));
}
}
```

**What happens**

The first push back goes well. It is doing what it's supposed to do. However, calling the push_back for the second time causes the following error:

```
main: malloc.c:2385: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

**My thoughts about this**

I think that the pointer to the vector is being changed after executing the first `push_back` command. Because the device has to reallocate memory. So while wanting to execute the second `push_back`, the pointer is pointing to an invalid location.

**What I tried to do to solve this**

I tried using `emplace_back` function, but I already knew that would not work.

Within the main of my program I am currently executing the following code, before calling the `processData` function:

```
products.reserve(100);
```

**Why?**

Because I thought this would allocate enough space for 100 `Product` pointers, so it would not reallocate memory.

Currently I am still having the issue as described above.
I hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

**Before using the code**

You will need to input some data. The data is looking like this:

```
#Data|<six numbers>|<two numbers>%
```

Example:

```
#Data|123456|12%
```

After putting in multiple ones, it will crash.
It seems like `removePrefix` is the causer, not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

#define END_MSG                 "End"
#define PRODUCT_NUMBER_LENGTH   6
#define AMOUNT_OF_SEPERATORS    2
#define STRING_BEGIN_INDEX      0

struct Product{
    int productNumber;
    int quantity;
    Product(int productNumber, int quantity) : productNumber(productNumber), quantity(quantity)
    {   
    }
};


void removePrefix(std::string* msg)
{
    if (msg != nullptr)
    {
        msg->erase(msg->begin());
        msg->erase(msg->end());
    }
}

void processData(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product>>& products)
{
    std::string DATA_MSG = "Data";
    std::string data;

    bool process = true;
    while (process)
    {
        std::cin >> data;
        removePrefix(&data);
        if (data.compare(END_MSG) != 0)
        {
            if (data.find(DATA_MSG) != std::string::npos &&
                    std::count(data.begin(), data.end(), '|') == AMOUNT_OF_SEPERATORS)
            {
                data.erase(STRING_BEGIN_INDEX, DATA_MSG.length() + 1); //including the first "|"
                int productNumber = std::stoi(data.substr(STRING_BEGIN_INDEX, PRODUCT_NUMBER_LENGTH));
                int quantity = std::stoi(data.substr(PRODUCT_NUMBER_LENGTH + 1));

                products.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Product>(new Product(productNumber, quantity)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            process = false;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product>> products;
    products.reserve(100);

    while (true)
    {
        processData(products);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: your interpretation is wrong. A vector reallocating will never change a pointer to the vector. The problem is very likely in code you did not post

Comment: In what situations would you call `processData` with a `nullptr`? You don't check if it's `nullptr` so I guess the answer is _never_. If so, why not make it a reference?

Comment: All you can say for certain is that something has corrupted the memory manager's state before this point. It could have happened pretty much anywhere. If your "simplified as much as possible" function triggers it, the problem is somewhere else. If it doesn't, you probably simplified too much, but the problem could still be somewhere else.

Comment: did you check that your reproducible example causes the error? Tbh i doubt it. You will rather run out of memory at some point due to the infinte loop

Comment: You say that `emplace_back` won't work, but doesn't `products->emplace_back(std::make_unique<Product>(dataA, dataB));` do the trick?

Comment: ...no it doesnt. [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9JkhsM). Please include a [mcve]

Comment: after fixing the typo it just runs forever until it gets killed or runs out of memory: https://godbolt.org/z/Dv4_9j

Comment: Allright, I will try to add a better one. Give me a few minutes :)

Comment: Here's some [food for thought](https://godbolt.org/z/edLymB)

Comment: At the moment i can not reproduce the error in simplified code.. don't know where else it should go wrong.. still investigating. Everytime I used GDB it crashed just before executing the push_back.

Comment: Is it better if I just put in all the code? It's not that much more.

Comment: If you didnt do it yet please read : [mcve]. The code should be complete and minimal. The more you can remove while still producing the error, the better

Comment: Your `Product` could just be `struct Product{};` for the [mcve] if I'm not mistaken? Did you take a look at my [food for thought](https://godbolt.org/z/edLymB) example?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, you are right. I just added a struct instead of the classes. Thanks

Comment: You still take the argument as a pointer instead of a reference in `processData` but you don't check for `nullptr`. Why?  The  `std::cin >> input` in `main` eats one line. Why?

Anyway: Here's the [AddressSanitizer](https://pastebin.com/E37NzWVq) output from running your program with the given input. Perhaps it'll help

Comment: @TedLyngmo my bad. I just changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like removePrefix is the causer, not sure.
>
> ```
> void removePrefix(std::string* msg)
> {
>     if (msg != nullptr)
>     {
>         msg->erase(msg->begin());
>         msg->erase(msg->end());
>     }
> }
> ```

`msg->end()` is an iterator one past the last character in the string. It does not refer to a character that you could remove from the string. Further you do check for `nullptr` but you do not check for the size of the string. If the string is empty, then `begin() == end()` and both calls will attempt to erase something which isn't there.

Please do not pass pointers everywhere when passing a  `nullptr` does not make sense. If you do not have a string then you would not call the function, so you never need to call it with a `nullptr`. Use references instead:

```
 void removePrefix(std::string& msg)
 {
     if (msg.size() >= 2) {
         msg.erase(msg.begin());
         msg.erase(msg.end() - 1);
     }
 }
```

PS: You have another call to erase:

```
data.erase(STRING_BEGIN_INDEX, DATA_MSG.length() + 1);
```

Also here I don't see that you make sure that the indices are in range. However, this will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception, which isnt the case for the iterator overload (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)).

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem is that unique_ptr has no copy constructor:
[Why can I not push_back a unique_ptr into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector)

push_back works as long as the instance **can** be moved.
For emplace_back the instance is created directly.
https://godbolt.org/z/26CHVj

-- edit: as idclev 463035818 noted, this would of course lead to a complile error and not a runtime error.
And yes, push_back has an r-reference overload and my statement about this is accordingly fuzzy and I have adjusted it.

Comment: that would be a compiler error, not a runtime error

Comment: `push_back` has an r-reference overload, and since the `unique_ptr` in OPs code is a temporary it does get moved