# C++ Adding new elements to a std::vector<unique_ptr<Object>>

Tags: c++

Currently using C++20, G++11.1.0.

What is the best way to add new elements to a vector of unique pointers?

I'm currently using `vec.emplace_back(new Object)`, which works well for me. In some instances, just doing `vec.emplace_back()` works as well (not sure if its supposed to though).

After reading through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector#comment11813799_3283795), I'm not sure what the best or safest method is. Should I even be using `emplace_back`? Or should I be using `push_back` instead?

Comment: So is it good to use `vec.emplace_back(new Object)`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `push_back` to work since `unique_ptr` is not copyable.

Comment: I would think `vec.emplace_back(make_unique<Object>())` should be used for exception safety. Perhaps somebody can confirm. `new`/`delete` should be avoided for normal code (not low level) as far as possible anyway (no RAII, exception safety and normally is red flag for not using smart pointers like `unique_ptr`).

Comment: @Sebastian What about `vec.emplace_back(make_unique<Object>())`?

Comment: Sorry, meant `make_unique` (what was I thinking/typing?), edited.

Comment: @jkb it is not copyable but moveable. `vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Object>())` should just work fine, as `push_back` supports move semantics.

Comment: @JakobStark Ah, forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: `emplace_back` would probably save a move operation compared to `push_back` or is it optimized anyway?

Comment: @Sebastian Actually in this case the object is already constructed in `std::make_unique` so `emplace_back` calls the move constructor, while `push_back` calls the move assignment operator. I am pretty sure they do the same thing under the hood.

Comment: Note that `vec.emplace_back(make_unique<Object>())` and `vec.push_back(make_unique<Object>())` are effectively equivalent. You can use any of these. In this demo, GCC generated the exact same assembly for both: https://godbolt.org/z/cqr5EcxMY.

Comment: C++ Weekly had the topic emplace_back vs push_back covered in 2021 so this may be of some relevance here: https://youtu.be/jKS9dSHkAZY